# doctest a phoenix context

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to elixir and phoenix and I wanted to doctest a newly created context (using `mix phx.gen.context`).

I have an `Accounts` context with a `User` schema.

I added to `accounts_test.exs` the following lines:

```
alias MyApp.Accounts.User
doctest MyApp.Accounts.User, import: true
```

And even fixed the default `change_user` documentation:

```
-     %Ecto.Changeset{source: %User{}}
+     %Ecto.Changeset{data: %User{}}
```

But I still have many, many, errors and warnings, as if it was basically not made to be doctested...

For example, the default generated doc puts:

> iex> `update_user(user, %{field: new_value})`
>   `{:ok, %User{}}`

This would issue:
warning: variable "new_value" does not exist and is being expanded to "new_value()"...
warning: variable "user" does not exist and is being expanded to "user()"...
test/my_app/accounts_test.exs:45: undefined function new_value/0
test/my_app/accounts_test.exs:45: undefined function user/0

My question is: is there something I'm missing? Or is it generally not common to doctest one's context (which would explain why it doesn't work out-of-the-box)

Comment: Could you share those `many, many, errors and warnings`? I little bit hard to say what is happening without seeing the error/warning.

Comment: @MarcosTapajós done, but it's not really helpful, it's the auto-generated code that really does not look like being made to be doctested...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking we do not doctest functions that have side-effects, such as context functions that have to read/write to the database, because they would require some amount of setup that is hard to cleanly portray in the doctest itself.

It is certainly doable but you should ask yourself if it is worth the effort. The Phoenix team itself seems to think it isn't. :)